# Query recursia MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

Estoy creando una página donde los clientes pueden crear su organigrama de la empresa y asignar a los responsables de cada departamento.

Cuando un usuario entra en la plataforma se le asigna el departamento automáticamente, pero si tiene acceso a más de uno tiene un selector donde puede seleccionar el departamento.

Los datos se guardan en dos bases de datos:

**organigrama**

[image: EXPLAIN organigrama]

| idElemento | idCliente | idSubCliente | idDeporte | idCategoria | idEquipo | idPadre | activo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | true |
| 202 | 15 | -1 | 2 | (null) | (null) | 201 | true |
| 203 | 15 | -1 | (null) | 7 | (null) | 202 | true |
| 204 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 100 | 203 | true |
| 205 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 101 | 203 | true |
| 206 | 15 | -1 | (null) | 4 | (null) | 202 | true |
| 209 | 15 | -1 | (null) | 2 | (null) | 202 | true |
| 212 | 15 | -1 | (null) | 3 | (null) | 202 | true |
| 213 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 106 | 206 | true |
| 214 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 107 | 206 | true |
| 215 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 108 | 209 | true |
| 216 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 109 | 209 | true |
| 217 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 110 | 212 | true |
| 218 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 111 | 212 | true |
| 219 | 15 | -1 | (null) | 1 | (null) | 202 | true |
| 220 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 112 | 219 | true |
| 221 | 15 | -1 | (null) | 5 | (null) | 202 | true |
| 222 | 15 | -1 | (null) | (null) | 113 | 221 | true |

**usuariosOrganigrama**.

[image: EXPLAIN usuariosOrganigrama]

| idReferencia | idCliente | idSubCliente | idUsuario | idElemento | activo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 131 | 15 | -1 | 4914 | 202 | true |
| 132 | 15 | -1 | 4914 | 205 | true |
| 134 | 15 | -1 | 4914 | 213 | true |

Os muestro un ejemplo:

[image: Estructura organigrana]

Como podéis ver hay una entidad, con varios deportes por debajo que a su vez tiene unas categorías deportivas con sus equipos.

Necesito una query que me recoja todos los elementos donde estoy posicionado y después subir hasta arriba hasta llegar a los deportes para determinar a que deportes tengo accesos y a que deportes no.

En el ejemplo anterior Cristian tendrá acceso a estos deportes: Fútbol y Fútbol Sala.

Hasta ahora estaba utilizando esta query que buscaba todos los registro del cliente y me devolvía solo los registros que tiene idDeporte.

```
with recursive elem as (
            select elem.idUsuario, elem.idElemento as root, o.idElemento, o.idPadre, o.idDeporte, o.activo
            from usuariosOrganigrama elem
            join organigrama o on o.idElemento = elem.idElemento
            where o.idCliente = 15 and o.idSubCliente = -1 and elem.activo = 1
                  and o.activo = 1 and  elem.idUsuario = 4914
           UNION ALL
            select elem.idUsuario, elem.root, o.idElemento, o.idPadre, o.idDeporte, o.activo
            from elem 
            join organigrama o on o.idElemento = elem.idPadre
          )
          select idElemento, idDeporte
          from elem
          where activo = 1 and idDeporte is not null
          group by idElemento
          order by idElemento
```

pero ahora con ~500 registros en organigrama y ~1000 en usuariosOrganigrama la query falla y me llena el espacio del disco duro (tengo que apagar y iniciar el maridb.service).

Que tengo que hacer para mejorar la query ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab7d26/1

Gracias.

Comment: La query tiene dos errores: El campo o.idDisciplina no existe (¿En su lugar hay que poner el campo o.idDeporte?). El segundo es que comparas el campo booleano activo con 'S' en lugar de con true.

Comment: He modificado la query, en lugar de idDisciplina tiene que ser idDeporte y en lugar de 'S'  1

Comment: Ayudaría ver el `EXPLAIN` de la consulta.

Comment: @Sal he añadido el EXPLAIN en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifiqué un poco tu query, probala a ver si mejora el rendimiento:

```
WITH recursive elemento AS (
            SELECT o.idElemento, o.idPadre, o.idDeporte
            FROM organigrama o
            INNER JOIN usuariosOrganigrama uo ON uo.idElemento = o.idElemento
            WHERE o.idCliente = 15 AND o.idSubCliente = -1 AND o.activo = true AND uo.activo = true AND uo.idUsuario = 4914 
          
           UNION ALL
           
            SELECT o.idElemento, o.idPadre, o.idDeporte
            FROM elemento e
            JOIN organigrama o on e.idPadre = o.idElemento
            WHERE o.idCliente = 15 and o.idSubCliente = -1 AND o.activo = true)
          
SELECT DISTINCT e.idElemento, e.idDeporte
FROM elemento e
WHERE e.idDeporte IS NOT NULL;
ORDER BY e.idElemento;
```

Salida (según los datos de ejemplo en sqlfiddle):

| idElemento | idDeporte |
| --- | --- |
| 202 | 2 |

Como podrás observar, la query retorna el campo idElemento e idDeporte (si no es nulo), pero no necesariamente el idElemento que está en usuariosOrganigrama, sino todos aquellos del arbol (hacia arriba) cuyo idDeporte no está vacio.

Comment: He puesto un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Sigo sin entender bien tu requerimiento. No logro ver la necesidad de utilizar una query recursiva (quizas el ejemplo de datos que has cargado no ayuda a que detecte el problema). Comentame porque esta query no cumple con lo que necesitas: `SELECT o.idElemento, o.idDeporte
FROM organigrama o
INNER JOIN usuariosOrganigrama uo ON uo.idElemento = o.idElemento
WHERE o.idCliente = 15 AND o.idSubCliente = -1 AND o.activo = true AND o.idDeporte IS NOT NULL
 AND uo.idUsuario = 4914;`

Comment: Ahora creo que lo entendí. Voy a rehacer la query y volverla a subir.

Comment: Modifiqué la query, creo que esta vez según tu requerimiento, pero no se si mejorará significativamente el rendimiento. Probala y cualquier cosa me avisas.

Comment: He probado tu query y pasa lo mismo (satura el servidor). Que valores me devolvería tu query en base al organigrama que pulique ? Solo Fútbol y Fútbol Sala o también baloncesto ?

Comment: Solo futbol y futbol sala. Si hubiera en esas ramas del arbol (de ese usuario) otro deporte también lo devolveríá, pero no los deportes que están en otras ramas.

Comment: No se me ocurre otra forma de hacer la query. Yo agregaríá la llave foranea y un indice con estos campos en organigrama (idCliente, idSubCliente, activo), a ver si mejora el rendimiento.

Comment: Ya tenia creado el indice  (idCliente, idSubCliente, activo) voy a cambiar la primary key a ver si consigo algo.

Comment: Si querés compartime las queries para crear las tablas y los inserts los podríá chequear, a ver que puede estar pasando. Me llama la atención poque tampoco son tantas filas.

Comment: He añadido [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab7d26/1) el create table y el insert, pero las comprobaciones las hago en el [SQL Lite Online](https://sqliteonline.com/) porque tiene MariaDB

Comment: Si, pero al no estar todos datos completos no puedo chequear que es lo que está pasando. Con los datos del ejemplo me funciona bien.

Comment: acabo de ver tu mensaje. https://mega.nz/file/HAAHnYRZ#iAwS9Z414KCdSRU5lP-77sN5AUZZS6SGG84Ujy2w4AI si haces clic en el icono que hay al lado del nombre del fichero podrás ver el contenido para copiarlo en el https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: Creo que encontré el problema: en el organigrama el registro que tiene idElemento 207 se tiene como padre a el mismo (idPadre = 207), y ahí se produce un bucle infinito.

Comment: También ocurre con el idElemento = 210. Si los datos no son consistentes respecto al modelo, el resultado de las queries no será el esperado.

Comment: Gracias por todo, pensé que había arreglado el error.

Comment: De nada @cplaiuu!!!